# Possible event handle leak in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, windbg, dump

Our Asp.Net web application seems to have some leaks, because it uses unusual amount of memory and many opened handles. Used handle from SysInternals to check all are of type Event. There are around 200k+ handles per hour.

I know it is not event handle like clicks etc. and it is related to locks, timers and another things, so it is not easy to detect source of them.

Checked dump and using `!dumpheap -stat` I got the most significant items

```
...
00007ff853c4a620   117529     10342552 System.ServiceModel.Description.MessagePartDescription
00007ff856578df8    19388     10547616 XXX.Providers.ISettingsItem`1[[System.String, mscorlib]][]
00007ff8a9eb8150   222047     10658256 System.Threading.ManualResetEvent
00007ff8a9e3fe28   450451     10810824 System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.CallContextSecurityData
00007ff84f63f788   221904     12426624 System.Runtime.Caching.CacheExpires
00007ff8a9ec3738   222171     12441576 System.Collections.Hashtable+HashtableEnumerator
00007ff84d384fd8   195746     14093712 System.Xml.Serialization.ElementAccessor
00007ff8a9eb43a0   226703     14508992 System.Threading.TimerCallback
00007ff855b9cc28   212423     16993840 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib],[XXX.Configuration.ModelValue, XXX.Configuration]]
00007ff850c48960   102466     17214288 XXX.ModelDefinition.Models.ComputedRisk
00007ff84eb81f00   314190     17594640 System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute
00007ff8a9eb4670   551441     17646112 System.Decimal
00007ff84f63a568   221904     17752320 System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCacheStore
00007ff8a9eb9fe0   449588     17983520 System.Collections.Stack
00007ff8a9e395e0   226835     19961480 System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer
00007ff84d38bcf8   165198     21145344 System.Xml.Serialization.MemberMapping
00007ff84f6b1020   221904     21302784 System.Runtime.Caching.UsageBucket
00007ff8a9ec9d80  1098447     26362728 System.Object
00007ff8a9ec4010   450469     32433768 System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.LogicalCallContext
00007ff8a9eb5b00   451141     39700408 System.Threading.ExecutionContext
00007ff8a9eca8f0    22780     49571828 System.Char[]
00007ff84f63fd40   221904     58582656 System.Runtime.Caching.ExpiresBucket[]
00007ff8a9ecd190   740049     59203920 System.Collections.Hashtable
00007ff8a9ec9e18   541051     60908584 System.Object[]
00007ff8a9eb13c8   961209    145744128 System.Collections.Hashtable+bucket[]
00007ff855ba6980   212423    181843056 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+Entry[[System.String, mscorlib],[XXX.Configuration.ModelValue, XXX.Configuration]][]
00007ff8a9ecc088  6978827    313669564 System.Int32[]
00007ff8a97b7ce8  4129359    330348720 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.Object, mscorlib]]
00007ff850bf6e60  4082662    522580736 XXX.Configuration.ModelValue
00007ff8a9ec97a0  6549932    622915972 System.String
00007ff84f63fcb0  6657120    639083520 System.Runtime.Caching.ExpiresBucket
00007ff8a9ecea48    65101    716832124 System.Byte[]
0000019223a6cd70  1331493   5145008822      Free
Total 48770037 objects
```

I just want to know, is it normal to have so many `ExpireBucket` entries? Does it mean all handles should be related to caching?

Any tips how to get more info?

**UPDATE**

Checked `GCRoot` and seems to be the same pattern

```
0:000> !gcroot 000001f413bb7c98
Thread 5394:
    0000009a997be3d0 00007ffc2291a702 System.Net.TimerThread.ThreadProc()
        rdi:  (interior)
            ->  000002001336bfd8 System.Object[]
            ->  000001ffd34177d8 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.Object, mscorlib],[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents+SystemEventInvokeInfo, System]], mscorlib]]
            ->  000001ffd34178d0 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+Entry[[System.Object, mscorlib],[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents+SystemEventInvokeInfo, System]], mscorlib]][]
            ->  000001ffd3417868 System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents+SystemEventInvokeInfo, System]]
            ->  000001ffd3417950 Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents+SystemEventInvokeInfo[]
            ->  000001ffd3417930 Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents+SystemEventInvokeInfo
            ->  000001f8d33730b0 System.Web.AspNetSynchronizationContext
            ->  000001f8d3373198 System.Web.AspNetSynchronizationContext+State
            ->  000001f8d33730d8 System.Web.Util.SynchronizationHelper
            ->  000001f8d3367058 ASP.global_asax
            ->  000001fed33686c0 System.Web.HttpApplicationState
            ->  000001fed3368768 System.Collections.ArrayList
            ->  000001fad33b5c98 System.Object[]
            ->  000001fad33b5c78 System.Collections.Specialized.NameObjectCollectionBase+NameObjectEntry
            ->  000001fad33b49d0 Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer
            ->  000001fad33b4b60 Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.LifetimeContainer
            ->  000001fad33b4b78 System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Object, mscorlib]]
            ->  000001fe13396698 System.Object[]
            ->  000001fb1339e080 Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ContainerControlledLifetimeManager
            ->  000001fb1339dda8 Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFactory
            ->  000001fb1339de88 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib],[Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging]]
            ->  000001f5537004c0 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+Entry[[System.String, mscorlib],[Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging]][]
            ->  000001f4d3626690 Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger
            ->  000001f4d36266b8 Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerInformation[]
            ->  000001f4d36266f0 Serilog.Extensions.Logging.SerilogLogger
            ->  000001fb1339df68 Serilog.Extensions.Logging.SerilogLoggerProvider
            ->  000001fb1339dfe0 Serilog.Core.Logger
            ->  000001fb1339dd60 Serilog.Core.Logger
            ->  000001fb1339d5a8 Serilog.Core.Sinks.SafeAggregateSink
            ->  000001fb1339d5c0 Serilog.Core.ILogEventSink[]
            ->  000001fb1339af98 Serilog.Sinks.Http.Private.NonDurable.HttpSink
            ->  000001fb1339b098 Serilog.Sinks.Http.Private.Time.PortableTimer
            ->  000001fb1339b120 System.Threading.Timer
            ->  000001fb1339b1f0 System.Threading.TimerHolder
            ->  000001fb1339b140 System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer
            ...
            300k x System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer
            ...
            ->  000001f413bb8670 System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer
            ->  000001f413bb8610 System.Threading.TimerCallback
            ->  000001f413bb73e8 System.Runtime.Caching.CacheExpires
            ->  000001f413bb7420 System.Runtime.Caching.ExpiresBucket[]
            ->  000001f413bb7c98 System.Runtime.Caching.ExpiresBucket

Failed to enumerate GC references.
Failed to walk thread 25ec
```

It is legacy WebForms application, with `Enterprise Library` blocks and with `Unity` version 3.5. As logger is used `Serilog`.

Comment: You can find an example to play with in https://gennadny.wordpress.com/2015/03/09/save-our-souls-troubleshooting-handle-leak-with-application-verifier-and-windbg-htrace-facilities/ Once you are familiar with the steps, you can then debug your own app.

Comment: I suggest to find the GCRoot of some of these objects to see why they are not GC'd.

Comment: Updated post with more info. It is hard for me to detect problem using !htrace, because of many opened handles and I just can't experimet on RTM server to attach debugger or restart IIS.